# Счетчик не изменяется

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    struct Word
    {
        int num;
        string text;
    };


    string text;
    Word word;
    word.num = 1;
    list<Word> wordList; //список
    bool wordRepeat = false;



    cout << "Введите текст нижним регистром, без знаков препинания и нажмите Enter \n";

    getline(cin, text); //вводим строк
    istringstream iss(text); //превращаем строку в поток
    while(iss >> word.text) //берем слово из потока
    {
        for(Word i : wordList)//проверяем на совпадения
        {
            if (word.text == i.text)
            {
                i.num++;
                //i.text = i.text + "+";
                wordRepeat = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!wordRepeat) wordList.push_back(word);
        wordRepeat = false;
    }

    for(Word i : wordList)//ВЫВОДИМ слова с кол-вом
    {
        cout << i.text << " " << i.num << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут

```
for(Word i : wordList)//проверяем на совпадения
    {
        if (word.text == i.text)
        {
            i.num++;
```

вы меняете счетчик В КОПИИ, а не в оригинале...

Вот так нужно:

```
for(Word& i : wordList)
```